# How to protect a site from (google) caching?

Tags: php

I would like to hide some content from public (like google cached pages). Is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Option 1: Disable 'Show Cached Site' Link In Google Search Results

If you want to prevent google from archiving your site, add the following meta tag to your  section:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noarchive">
```

If your site is already cached by Google, you can request its removal using [Google's URL removal tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals?pli=1). For more instructions on how to use this tool, see ["Remove a page or site from Google's search results"](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=164734&from=35301&rd=1) at Google Webmaster Central.

### Option 2: Remove Site From Google Index Completely

**Warning! The following method will remove your site from Google index completely. Use it only if you don't want your site to show up in Google results.**

To prevent ("protect") your site from getting to Google's cache, you can use `robots.txt`. For instructions on how to use this file, see ["Block or remove pages using a robots.txt file"](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hlrm=fi&answer=156449).

In principle, you need to create a file named `robots.txt` and serve it from your site's root folder (`/robots.txt`). Sample file content:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /folder1/

User-Agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /folder2/
```

In addition, consider setting `robots` *meta tag* in your HTML document to `noindex` (["Using meta tags to block access to your site"](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=93710)):

- To prevent all robots from indexing your site, set `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">`
- To *selectively block only Google*, set `<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">`

**Finally, make sure that your settings really work, for instance with [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en)**.

Comment: This answer (and possibly the question) confuses Google caching with Google indexing. Indexing is listing the site in the search engine and caching is storing a copy of the pages on Google. Both are different. Google's removal tool removes pages altogether from the Google index but if the questioner wants to only stop Google caching his pages, this is a different answer. The question and answer should refer to either caching or indexing and provide the appropriate method for the term used. Currently this answer removes content from the index which, by default, also removes it from the cache.

Comment: @jsalonen Would you mind removing your answer? It's totally wrong and might mislead people....

Comment: @Abatonime I cannot remove the answer until the accepted answer is changed.

Comment: @jsalonen I suggested an Edit. I feel like editing to put the right answer is unfair to dogbane

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I changed the answer type to community wiki and merged together my answer with the solution from @Dogbane to provide more complete answer.

Answer (score 28):

Add the following HTML tag in the `<head>` section of your web pages to prevent Google from showing the Cached link for a page.

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="noarchive">
```

Check out [Google webmaster central | Meta tags](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=79812) to see what other meta tags Google understands.

Comment: @user669677 If a bot does whatever it wants, then you don't have a choice.

Comment: This is the correct answer. All of the others prevent sites from being indexed and found in the search results. That's not what the user wants. They just want to prevent caching and this is exactly how it's done.

Answer (score 2):

robots.txt: http://www.robotstxt.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `robots.txt` file to request that your page is not indexed. Google and other reputable services will adhere to this, but not all do.

The only way to make sure that your site content isn't indexed or cached by any search engine or similar service is to prevent access to the site unless the user has a password.

This is most easily achieved using [HTTP Basic Auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). If you're using the Apache web server, there are lots of tutorials ([example](http://www.colostate.edu/~ric/htpass.html)) on how to configure this. A good search term to use is `htpasswd`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this would be with a `<meta name="robots" content="noarchive"/>`

You can also achieve a similar effect with the robots.txt file.

For a good explanation, see the [official google blog on the robot's execution policy](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2007/02/robots-exclusion-protocol.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can also add this HTTP Header on your response, instead of needing to update the html files:

```
X-Robots-Tag: noarchive
```

eg for Apache:

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noarchive"
```

See also: https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag?csw=1

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to hide some content from public....

Use a login system to view the content.

> ...(like google cached pages).

Configure `robots.txt` to deny Google bot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit who can see content, secure it behind some form of authentication mechanism (e.g. password protection, even if it is just HTTP Basic Auth).

The specifics of how to implement that would depend on the options provided by your server.